# Shutting down Windows machines via WMI script

Tags: python, linux, winapi, wmi

I have a Python script running on a Linux machine that uses `WMI` to retrieve data about local Windows machines.

Currently I am only retrieving information from them via `WMI` queries and I am unsure of how to send it commands to perform. I want to be able to send a shutdown command using the `wmi` class defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

I am currently fetching information as shown below:

```
import wmi_client_wrapper as wmi
wmic = wmi.WmiClientWrapper(username="Administrator", password="password", host=ip,)
disk = wmic.query("SELECT Size,FreeSpace FROM Win32_LogicalDisk")
```

I am using the `wmi_client_wrapper` [python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wmi-client-wrapper) to programmatically query for data via `wmi`. How would I use this package to go about sending the shutdown command via `wmi`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Python package being used, `wmi_client_wrapper`, implements a wmi object that only has the following methods:

`['_construct_query', '_fix_dictionary_output', '_make_credential_args', '_parse_wmic_output', '_setup_params', 'query']`

of which only the `query` method makes calls directly to the `WMI` interface of the windows machine being targeted. Since `WMI` queries can only possibly [retrieve](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/46390/wmi-query-language-by-example) data, that means that if restricted to just being able to query, the package being used cannot send commands via `WMI` to your target machine.